# Can I make a bot global check return a useful value instead of a bool?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, python-decorators

I'm trying to implement a global check for my Discord bot in Python, through the **`@bot.check`** decorator.

The check's purpose is to verify if the command author's ID can be found in a MongoDB collection and if so, to extract the relevant data.

What I'd like to accomplish is to pass the extracted data to the actual commands, thus avoiding querying the database again.

As per discord.py docs, the `check()` decorator is only able to evaluate the result as a True or False-like value and raise a `CheckFailure` in the latter case.

Here's a simplified example of my situation:

```
@bot.check
async def is_member(ctx):
    member = mongo_collection.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id}) # first query
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("You need to join the community first!")
    return member

@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    member = mongo_collection.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id}) # redundant
    ...
```

Theoretically I could define a custom decorator for the purpose, but then I would have to specify it before each command.
I could even create a Bot subclass that overrides the check methods and the decorator, but I think it's kind of an overwork for such a simple issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do that, but you can create your own instance variable

```py
@bot.check
async def is_member(ctx):
    member = mongo_collection.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id}) # first query
    ctx.mongo_member = member 
    return member is not None


@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    member = ctx.mongo_member
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Just tought that Context was equipped with ____slots____ like many other discord objects.

Comment: Good for us it doesn’t, but you can still make your own custom context, see https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/custom_context.py